MUI Select Label WAVE Accessibility Fail v6.1.6
The following component is what MUI provides as an accessibility examples for the select component in current version 6.1.6
<FormControl fullWidth>
  <InputLabel id="label">Age</InputLabel>
  <Select labelId="label" id="select" value="20">
    <MenuItem value="10">Ten</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value="20">Twenty</MenuItem>
  </Select>
</FormControl>

When tested with WAVE, I get a Missing form label alert and an Orphaned form label alert. Has anyone else experienced this or resolved it?
